# Load an img src as a background image for the Div it resides in with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working with SharePoint and I have to deal with a few corporate issues in using Open Source... plus have to make the site easy for someone to edit. I'm using jQuery and Cycle v.3.0.2 to run a slider. I'm about to rip apart my slider to allow it to use captions, so I will use an individual div per slide. I want to have an img element and a text element to run as a caption, and since the slider is full width, I'd love it if I can pull that img tag's src attribute and apply it to the overall div as a background image when the particular slide loads. Is there a way to make this happen? I see the coding being like this:

```
<div id="slider">
<div class="sliderIMG">
    <img src="http://urURL.com/img1" />
    <h4>Your Caption for Slider <a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">Button</a></h4>
</div>
<div class="sliderIMG">
    <img src="http://urURL.com/img1" />
    <h4>Your Caption for Slider <a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">Button</a></h4>
</div>
<div class="sliderIMG">
    <img src="http://urURL.com/img1" />
    <h4>Your Caption for Slider <a class="button" href="#" target="_blank">Button</a></h4>
</div>
```

Is there a way that I can call it to add a style tag to the .sliderIMG div and add the background image inline using the img src that resides in the this div? Also, there is a class for the active slide named 'active' if that helps me in getting the correct src attribute.

Answer (score 2):

```
var src = $('.sliderIMG').children('img').attr('src');
$('.sliderIMG').css('background-image', 'url(' + src + '');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3h6pqyod/

And as another poster said, you can iterate over all divs like this:

```
$('.sliderIMG').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).children //etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two obvious approaches; one is to iterate over the `<img>` elements:

```
// selects all <img> elements within an element of the
// class 'sliderIMG', then iterates over that collection:
$('.sliderIMG img').each(function(){

    // finding the closest ancestor element matching
    // the '.sliderIMG' selector, and updating its
    // 'background-image', property-value using the
    // css() method, to the property held in the
    // <img> element's 'src' property:
    $(this).closest('.sliderIMG').css('background-image', this.src);
});
```

Or you can iterate over the `.sliderIMG` elements:

```
// selecting all '.sliderIMG' elements, and updating its
// 'background-image' property, using the anonymous function
// of the css() method; in which we find the descendant <img>
// element(s) and then return the 'src' property of the
// first <img> in that collection:
$('.sliderIMG').css('background-image', function (){
    return $(this).find('img').prop('src');
});
```

In plain JavaScript the following enables the same functionality:

```
// using document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve all
// elements matching the supplied CSS selector:
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.sliderIMG img'),

    // using Array.from() to convert the returned
    // HTMLCollection into an Array:
    imageArray = Array.from( images );

    // or, in older browsers; here we use
    // Array.prototype.slice() with
    // Function.prototype.call() to create an
    // Array from the HTMLCollection:
    // imageArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(images, 0);

// iterating over the Array of images with
// Array.prototype.forEach():
imageArray.forEach(function (img) {
    // the first argument of the forEach
    // anonymous function is a reference
    // to the Array element of the Array
    // over which we're iterating.

    // here we find the parentNode of the <img>
    // and directly update its 'background-image'
    // to that of the <img> element's src property:
    img.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = img.src;
});
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
- jQuery:

  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).