# How to take the 'src' from an image in a post and make it a background image just for that post with jquery when there's multiple posts on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, background-image

Sorry if that question is a mouthful. Basically here's what I'm trying to do:

Here's the html markup:

```
<article class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="copy">
        <h1 class="index-name"><span>Jean-Michel Basquiat</span></h1>
        <div class="article-summary">
            <img src="img/profiles/profile_jbasquiat.jpg"/>
            <h2>Preview Copy</h2>
            <a href="#" class="read-more serif">read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

<article class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="copy">
        <h1 class="index-name"><span>Lorraine Vivian Hansberry</span></h1>
        <div class="article-summary">
            <img src="img/profiles/profile_lhansberry.jpg"/>
            <h2>Preview Copy</h2>
            <a href="#" class="read-more serif">read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

So what I'm trying to do is take the `src` for the `img` element in each `div` with the class `.article-summary`, then make that the background image of the related `div` with the class `.image` above. Now I have been successful with this script in the past, but only when I'm on an individual page for each of these posts. It targets everything, so I get the same image for all of the background images:

```
var img = $('.article-summary img').attr('src');
$('.image').css('background-image', 'url('+img+')');
```

I was looking around and found this script on another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792338/load-an-img-src-as-a-background-image-for-the-div-it-resides-in-with-jquery), but I can't get it working either. My images just show up blank. I'm not an expert on the logic of how the JavaScript is working, so I thought I'd ask the experts here.

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: share your example on jsbin or codepen , it should work, you might be missing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.swiper-slide').each(function(){

  var img = $(this).find('.article-summary img').attr('src');
  $(this).find('.image').css('background-image', 'url('+img+')');
});
```

You need to do it for each slide - something like the above should work.